# Copy Outlook Groups to Excel with Python

Tags: python, outlook

First post.  Forgive me if I make an rookie mistakes.

In my outlook at work, there are several groups with members.  For example, there is a BusinessGroup, FacultyGroup, StudentsGroup, ScienceGroup, etc.  Is there any easy way to write a Python script and put it into an Excel spreadsheet?

The alternative which is to manually look up each member of each group and record him in Excel is tedious, painfully slow, and inaccurate.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Best,
J

Comment: Where does the group come from? Exchange GAL? Or your Contacts folder?

Comment: Hi, not sure if this will answer the question.  So when initiate an e-mail and click on To: I can see in the text field pre-existing groups.

Comment: Both GAL and local distribution lists from your Contacts folder are shown there, so the question still stands.

Comment: OK I believe it's from the Exchange GAL.

Comment: I see a message in the title bar 'Select Names: Offline Global Address List' so I believe it's from the GAL.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following (VBA, shouldn't be too hard to translate to Python):

```
dim address
set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
set list = App.Session.AddressLists.Item("All Users")
for each entry in list.AddressEntries
  if entry.Type= "EX" Then
    address = entry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
  Else
    address = entry.Address
  End If
  Debug.Print entry.Name & " " & address
next
```